# Design of JWT authentication?

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework, jwt, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I am using DjangoRest Framework simple-jwt package found at https://github.com/davesque/django-rest-framework-simplejwt.

this provides two api endpoints to get access token and refresh token. Currently I store the access token in localStorage in browser. Is this the best place to store it, or would sessionStorage be better?

When I need a new access token because the current access token expired, should I pass the refresh token (stored in localStorage) in a POST request? Is this the best implementation? It seems insecure to have this crucial refresh token string stored in the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That works and yes, you would pass the refresh token. Since you're using it for a web app I suggest you make your access token and refresh tokens expire rather quickly this way it's always generating a new one.

Comment: I understand that this works. I am specifically asking if this is a good design, because if your refresh token is compromised then an adversary will have access to your data for a long period of time. Making the refresh token expire quickly defeats the purpose I think, the purpose being a better UX by not having to frequently re-login. So is using browser storage secure? Or should I be trying to store this token on the back end in some sort of session instance. You also did not comment on whether session or local storage is a better choice.

Comment: There is a risk of the refresh token being compromised no matter where you store it and that's just reality. JWT tokens are not meant to be stored in a backend or database. I store mine in the client (local storage) and it works just fine. I also think at some point you should sign out the user if they've been inactive and their refresh token has expired. It's web, not an app and usually computers are shared. It all depends on the application type you're building and there are several methods to not sign out the user and generate new tokens.

Comment: Thank you, that's very helpful. Could you list a couple of methods to not sign out the user that I can look into?

Comment: 1. You can store the users email and password along with the tokens and request new tokens with the credentials when the user becomes active again.
2. Never expire the refresh token and record which device user is on. Then check if user signs in from a different device and alert the user. User can then say it's me or log out user and change password.